# how to colour user selected option using CSS in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

The following code highlights a selected option in Google chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    select option:checked { background: #f00; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

however it does not work in Mozilla Firefox!

Any ideas on the CSS to make the same behaviour work for firefox?

Comment: IMO i'd make it with click function in js, but that probably does not answer your question

Comment: trouble is I am using the keyboard arrows to navigate the select control, I can do it with events, but there must be a correct solution

Comment: jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/5z2rvfr1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

again you can't use background-color, I've tried background:linear-gradient (..) and it worked for me in ff.

```
option:hover,
option:focus,
option:active,
select option:checked {
  background: linear-gradient(#5A2569, #5A2569);
}
```

Comment: Just tested and this works for me as well on Firefox

Answer (score 0):

try: 
option[selected] { background: #f00; }

Comment: doesn't even work in chrome then (there is no selected option)

Comment: what system you are on?

Comment: Linux 3.13.0-86-generic #130-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I think you can't style it.  This element is rendered by the OS, not HTML. It cannot be styled via CSS. The only way is to use js which make the select from the elements you can style. I use http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/selects 
or angular-ui select directive
https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/
or https://github.com/HubSpot/select

Comment: the example that I gave above works in Google Chrome on Linux but not on Firefox on Linux, I don't think it is an OS problem. Try it out on the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5z2rvfr1/

Comment: maybe this could help here is link from mozzillademos, second select is styled - it work on field set https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4563/editable_select.html